# ConvertTo-Html cmdlet how to add columns to output

Tags: html, css, powershell

I am currently working on a PowerShell script that converts text file reports into a series of tables in a `HTML` file using the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet. A section in the text file look something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦Operating System Info:                                                   ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Operating System:   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard  
Service Pack:       Service Pack 1
Product Type:       Server
Product ID:         55041-266-0358183-84672
Architecture:       64-bit
Install Date:       2013-04-11 11:58:26  
Encryption Level:   256 bit
Local Time:         2016-02-18 08:06:58  
Last Bootup Time:   2015-08-13 07:10:00  
Total Physical Memory:  18863924 KB
Free Physical Memory:   14811704 KB
Total Virtual Memory:   37725992 KB
Free Virtual Memory:    33103616 KB
Data Execution Prev:    DEP is enabled for Windows services only (OptIn - Windows Default)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦Computer Info:                                                           ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Computer Name:      COMPNAME
DNSHostName:        COMPNAME
Pinging aaccms2 [172.20.78.132] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.20.78.132: bytes=32 time
```

[image: ![Service Pack: Service Pack 1]

Instead of keeping the spacing it had earlier.

So my questions is, is there any way I can get the table to split into a new column after a certain character or set of characters, like say ": "? I have also made a few tests that append things to the file before it is written to `HTML` resulting in things like:

```
Total Physical Memory: 16000000 KB: PASS
```

So if I could split it into three columns, one for the title, one for the value, and one for the pass fail that would be even better. My PowerShell conversion looks like this:

```bsh
foreach ($Line in $Table) {
    # Converts each line to HTML output, does not include lines that have
    # text file spacers, blank lines, or titles in the line (titles added
    # later)

    if ($Line -ne "+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+" `
     -and $Line -ne "+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+" `
     -and $Line -ne "" `
     -and $Line -ne $Titles[$count]) {
        $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $Object -Type NoteProperty -Name AACC -Value $Line
        $Document += $Object
    }
}

$CurrentTitle = $Titles[$count]
$Frag += $Document |
    ConvertTo-Html -As TABLE -Fragment -PreContent "<h2 align = center id = $CurrentTitle;> $CurrentTitle  </h2>" |
    Out-String   # Adds the new HTML fragment (table) to the frag array

ConvertTo-Html -Title $FileName -Head $head -PostContent $Frag -Property AACC -Body $Body |
    Out-File $TargetFile   # Outputs the new HTML file
```

The `$head` variable where I set up the table layout looks like

```bsh
$Title = "<title> $Filename Report</title>"

$CSSStyle = @'
<style>
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
body { background-color:White;
  font-family:Tahoma;
  font-size:12pt;
}
td, th {border:1px solid black;} 
th {
  color: black;
  background-color:#C11B17;
}
td { border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black; }
TR:Hover TD { Background-Color: #C1D5F8; }
table, tr, td, th { align:left; padding: 2px; margin: 0px; }
table { width:100% }
table { margin-left:0px; }
</style>
'@

$Head = $Title + $CSSStyle
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start to filter all unecessary lines using a simple regex:

```
Get-Content 'your_file' | Where { $_.Trim() -notmatch '[+¦]|^$' }
```

**Ouput:**

```
Operating System:        Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard  
Service Pack:            Service Pack 1
Product Type:            Server
Product ID:              1234-5678
Architecture:            64-bit
Install Date:            2013-01-01 01:01:01  
Encryption Level:        256 bit`
Total Physical Memory:   16000000 KB
```

---

Then use another regex to capture the keys and values and create a `PSCustomObject` from it:

```
Get-Content 'your_file' | Where { $_.Trim() -notmatch '[+¦]|^$' } | foreach { 
    $regexMatch = [regex]::Match($_.Trim(), '(?<Key>[^:]+):\s+(?<Value>.+)')
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key = $regexMatch.Groups['Key'].Value
        Value = $regexMatch.Groups['Value'].Value
    }    
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key                   Value                                    
---                   -----                                    
Operating System      Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Service Pack          Service Pack 1                           
Product Type          Server                                   
Product ID            1234-5678                                
Architecture          64-bit                                   
Install Date          2013-01-01 01:01:01                      
Encryption Level      256 bit`                                 
Total Physical Memory 16000000 KB
```

---

Now you can pipe the output to the [ConvertTo-Html](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113290) cmdlet:

```
Get-Content 'your_file' | Where { $_.Trim() -notmatch '[+¦]|^$' } | foreach { 
    $regexMatch = [regex]::Match($_.Trim(), '(?<Key>[^:]+):\s+(?<Value>.+)')
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key = $regexMatch.Groups['Key'].Value
        Value = $regexMatch.Groups['Value'].Value
    }    
} |  ConvertTo-Html -Title $FileName -Head $head | out-file $TargetFile
```

**Output:**
[image]

---

**Edit to your comment:**

I would start to seperate the sections:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file'
$headings = $content | sls '\s*¦' | 
    select LineNumber, @{l="heading"; e={[regex]::Match($_.Line, '¦([^:]+)').Groups[1].Value}}, Content

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $headings.Count; $i++)
{
    if ($i +1 -lt $headings.Count)
    {
        $headings[$i].Content = ($content[$headings[$i].LineNumber .. $headings[$i +1].LineNumber]).Trim() -notmatch '[+¦]|^$'
    }
    else # last entry
    {
        $headings[$i].Content = ($content | select -skip $headings[$i].LineNumber).Trim() -notmatch '[+¦]|^$'
    }    
}
```

Which will give you the heading and the content of the section (`$headings | select heading, Content`):

```
heading               Content                                                                                                                                                             
-------               -------                                                                                                                                                             
Operating System Info {Operating System:   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Service Pack:       Service Pack 1, Product Type:       Server, Product ID:         55041-266-035...
Computer Info         {Computer Name:      COMPNAME, DNSHostName:        COMPNAME, Pinging aaccms2 [172.20.78.132] with 32 bytes of data:, Reply from 172.20.78.132: bytes=32 time}
```

Now all you have to do is to combine the two scripts.

Comment: Regex capture group names ... so shiny. Read about that a few days ago, really makes the capture groups easier to use. Very nice.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but do you have any idea how you would get this to work for multiple tables? The main problem I'm having is getting this to apply to the individual table fragments (where I use the -frag parameter in the above script). I can get it to work if there is only one table in the text file, but there are many, including things like Computer Info, Drive Information, etc.

Comment: I thought you would be able to do this for yourself. If you add another table on the example, I will take a look.

Comment: I've updated the post with the new table, in the mean time I'll keep trying to get it to work, hopefully I can get it going on my own

Comment: Input format is now totally different, and a bit dirty in the end (`ping ...`).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have been a bit more clear in the question. That's why I'm trying to just separate after ": ", it seems to be the best combination of characters for segregating the entries

Comment: Even if that wouldn't create a separate column in every case, it would be fine for my purposes.

Comment: I edited my answer but left you some work to bring both scripts together.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Do you know of anywhere where I could read up on regular expressions, so I can better understand how to work with things in the first part of your script like "{ $_.Trim() -notmatch '[+¦]|^$' }" and " $_.Trim(), '(?<Key>[^:]+):\s+(?<Value>.+)' "?

Comment: @MartinBrandl Did you test the first part of your script with the updated input? It seems like it wipes any line that does not contain a semi colon. This occurs with the 2nd last line of the updated input, "pinging"

Comment: No I did not. But the problem is probably because the entry ping & reply is split into two lines. You need to fix that by finding such lines (say where a `:` is the last character) and append the next line to it. If you don't get it to work, please start another question. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I figured it out. For anyone dealing with this problem in future, custom objects are definitely the way to go for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

A custom object with all the needed properties will be easier to manipulate and export. This should help you get the columns you want:

```
$inputLines = Get-Content "input.txt"

#create custom object
$result = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject

$inputLines |
    #skip lines containing ¦ or -----
    Where-Object { $_ -NotMatch "\¦|-----" } | ForEach-Object {   

    $lineArray = $_.Split(":")

    #add property to custom object
    if($lineArray[0]) {

        $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
            -Name $lineArray[0].Trim() `
            -Value (($lineArray | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join ":").Trim()

    }
}

#export to HTML file
$result | ConvertTo-Html -As List | Out-File "output.html"
```

Note: the `;` after `$CurrentTitle` is not needed (it will be output in the HTML code).

*Note 2: final credits go to Martin Brandl who kindly pointed out a bug ... and then helped me fix it.*

Comment: `Split` is probably not a good idea here consider the `Install Date`.

Comment: ... I wish you were sitting next to me when I write code. I had to double-check the output HTML since I would not get an error because of this ... DAMN! At least I got a vote up : )

Comment: :-). You can adopt your answer to use `-Value $lineArray[1 .. -1]`

Comment: With your hack, values get turned into `System.Object[]`. Tried to `-join ":"` back again but this gets a bit ugly : ).

Comment: You are right, its getting ugly. I ended up with `(($lineArray | select -Skip 1) -join '').Trim()`

Comment: `(($lineArray | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join ":").Trim()` does it (to keep the `:`'s in the value). I'll udpate, thank you very much.